# How can I see what gems are available at a particular github url?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, github, bundle

This is a pretty basic question about how the bundler looks up gems.

While trying to revert to a previous version of a gem I'm using in my Rails application, I get the following `bundle install` error:

```
Could not find gem 'client_side_validations (= 3.2.0.beta.3) ruby' in https://github.com/bcardarella/client_side_validations.git (at master).
Source contains 'client_side_validations' at: 3.2.0.beta.6
```

Which is totally weird because I was on 3.2.0.beta.3 a few days ago and the bulder was happy.

I'm super curious to find out what versions of the gem are available though the url ('https://github.com/bcardarella/client_side_validations.git') to the bundler. How do I go about doing that?

Comment: Obviously if I go to https://github.com/bcardarella/client_side_validations.git, I'll get redirected to the project's github page. But I'm unsure of what the bundler uses as the source -- a tag? a commit? something else?

Comment: Why do you use the github source and not the rubygems.org source?

Comment: That's a good question @Wukerplank. I think I had done that earlier to make it work...but I removed it and it works find now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bundler pulls the source from the master branch and it gets the version of the gem [here](https://github.com/bcardarella/client_side_validations/blob/master/lib/client_side_validations/version.rb)